# Настройки axis2 для https

Tags: apache, tomcat, axis2

Есть axis2 на томкате, сам сайт работает только по `https` все работает кроме того ссылок внутри `axis`2, открывается эта страница к примеру `https://testp.kor.com/axis2/` а вот сслыки внутри него ссылаются без `https` и из за этого не открываются эти страницы, пишет что не доступен, а если подставить https перед адресом к примеру в сервисы то открывает, как можно это исправить ведь в томкате настроен редирект но не помогает, может это настраивается где то в axis вроде бы в томкате настроен редирект на 443 порт

```
<Connector acceptCount="70" connectionTimeout="20000"
        disableUploadTimeout="false" port="82"  redirectPort="443"
            address="127.0.0.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8" debug="99">
</Connector>         
<Connector acceptCount="70" connectionTimeout="20000"
        disableUploadTimeout="false" port="8080"  redirectPort="443"
    address="127.0.0.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8" debug="99">
</Connector>           
<Connector acceptCount="70" connectionTimeout="20000"
      disableUploadTimeout="false" port="82"  redirectPort="443"
     address="10.0.27.32" URIEncoding="UTF-8" debug="99">
     </Connector>`
```

Когда я захожу по локальному адресу с указанием порта `10.0.20.38:82`, ссылается он нормально, `10.0.20.38:82/axis2/service` а вот если заходить из внешки по адресу на стриницу `https://testp.kor.com/axis2`, то ссылки внутри этой стрницы указывает ссылки без https, показывает просто `testp.kor.com/axis2` и в итоге не открывается страница, может это как то настраивается в axis

Comment: Транспорт указывали? https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html

Comment: Поясняю ситуацию тем, кто ничего не в курсе. У автора перед Томкатом стоит реверс-прокси, который терминирует SSL. Поэтому запросы до сервера доходят уже по незащищенному протоколу - но ссылки надо, не смотря на это, отдавать со схемой `https://`.Проблема - не в привязках SOAP, а именно в отображении служебных страниц.

Comment: да https-transport есть, да https://testpay.kkb.kz/axis2/ вот здесь видно что ссылки он создает Без https и потому не работает, хотя в менеджере томката все нормальные ссылки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел исходники.

За вывод данной страницы отвечает исходный файл [`/modules/webapp/src/main/webapp/axis2-web/index.jsp`](https://github.com/apache/axis2-java/blob/1_5/modules/webapp/src/main/webapp/axis2-web/index.jsp). Конкретно `baseurl` получается в файле [`/webapp/src/main/webapp/axis2-web/include/httpbase.jsp`](https://github.com/apache/axis2-java/blob/1_5/modules/webapp/src/main/webapp/axis2-web/include/httpbase.jsp).

За определение `baseurl` отвечает параметр `HTTP_FRONTEND_HOST_URL`, остаётся выяснить откуда мы его получаем.

А получаем мы его, насколько я понял, всё из того же файла `\axis2\WEB-INF\conf\axis2.xml`.

Попробуйте, если проблема ещё актуальна (что вряд ли, но ответ может пригодиться другим) при определении HTTPS-транспорта в Axis2 указать ещё параметр `httpFrontendHostUrl`:

```
<transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender">
    <parameter name="PROTOCOL">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
    <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding">chunked</parameter>
    <parameter name="httpFrontendHostUrl">https://testpay.kkb.kz/axis2/</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

У меня сейчас под рукой нет работающего Tomcat с HTTPS, поэтому проверить данную гипотезу я не могу. Буду благодарен, если кто-то подтвердит или опровергнет мой ответ. В любом случае, где искать теперь понятно, параметр, значение которого надо установить, мы определили, так что дальнейшие поиски в случае неудачи будут легче.

Answer (score -1):

> > testpay.kkb.kz/axis2 вот здесь видно что ссылки он создает Без https и потому не работает

Ссылки он создает верно. не работает потому что стоит

```
<base href="http://testpay.kkb.kz/axis2/"/>
```

либо уберите этот тег вообще, либо пишите его без протокола (по умолчанию без указания протокола используется текущий)

```
<base href="testpay.kkb.kz/axis2/"/>
```

Comment: Вот именно эти ссылки не я создаю, это приложение axis2 которое я установил в tomcat, и это прилоежние почему то не правильно подставляет.